# Fetch a URL 100 times using Perl

Tags: perl, loops, lwp

The problem I met is that I need to get one URL (I cannot be specific that link exactly, this link is doing request and looks like http://link.com/?name=name&password=password& and etc)

And I need to fetch this URL 100 times in a row. I can not do this manually using browser - this takes much time.

Is there any option to run (just run, like you put link in browser and press enter) this link 100 times in a row using Perl scripting?

I have not met before with the Perl and therefore asking the help directly. As I google before some information and make a little script, but seems like I missing something in my knowledge:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use LWP::Simple;
my $uri =  'http://my link here';
my $content = get $uri;
```

Could you please advise to me how I can finish this script?

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` at the top, and remove `-w`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a (simple) `for` loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;
my $uri =  'http://my link here';
get $uri for 1 .. 100;
```

**Update:** Just read in a comment that you don't care about the returned data, so I've edited my answer to remove the unnecessary `$content` variable.